# Finding URLs that redirect to a given website

Tags: domains, redirects, url, 301-redirect

Is there any way to find all URLs that (permanently) redirect to a given website?

E.g. `example.redirect` redirects to `www.example.com`. So I'd want a way to determine that `example.redirect` redirects without already knowing that `example.redirect` exists ex-ante.

Comment: Are you talking about websites that redirect to your website in some fashion?

Comment: I closed this because it appears to be about finding information about other people's websites rather than about running one of your own.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible without the help of a third party tool/spider/bot that has already crawled these redirects and stored this information (eg. a search engine).

At `www.example.com` you have no way of knowing whether the request arrived via a redirection from `example.redirect`, since the request comes from the client's machine (user-agent) not `example.redirect`. Neither is `example.redirect` the HTTP `Referer`, unlike when a user clicks a link on `example.redirect`.